# Keep track of draggable div in jquery ui?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is it possible to keep track of jquery ui draggable divs? I'm trying to hide all divs that has not been moved/dragged and only showing the divs that have been moved.

Comment: Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I would suggest using the `stop` event for the Draggable to tag the element with a Class. This way you can easily select the moved items. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and we can assist further. It would also be best to take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Consider an example like this.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable({
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      $(this).addClass("moved");
    }
  });
  $(".action").click(function() {
    if ($(this).text().indexOf("Hide") != -1) {
      $(".moved").css("opacity", 0);
      $(this).html("Reveal Moved");
    } else {
      $(".moved").css("opacity", 1);
      $(this).html("Hide Moved");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.draggable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<button class="action">Hide Moved</button>

<div class="ui-widget-content draggable">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
<div class="ui-widget-content draggable">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
<div class="ui-widget-content draggable">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
<div class="ui-widget-content draggable">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
<div class="ui-widget-content draggable">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
```

You can use `.show()` and `.hide()` but these will change the display to None. Opacity or Visible might be better to retain flow.

**Update**

You commented with the following code:

```
function showHideImages(){
  let moved = document.getElementsByClassName('newClass');
  if (moved.length > 0) {
    $('.ui-draggable:not(.newClass)').hide();
    document.querySelector('#hideShowButton').innerHTML='Show images';
  } else {
    $('.ui-draggable:not(.newClass)').show();
    document.querySelector('#hideShowButton').innerHTML='Hide images';
}
```

It would be best to use all jQuery or all JavaScript. You don't have to, it's just better practice. So we can clean up the code like so:

```
function showHideImages(){
  var notMoved = $('.ui-draggable').not(".newClass");
  if (notMoved.length > 0) {
    notMoved.hide();
    $('#hideShowButton').html('Show images');
  } else {
    notMoved.show();
    $('#hideShowButton').html('Hide images');
}
```

Comment: Ok I didnt know there was a `stop` event I was experimenting with the `drag` event and added a class. I am new to Stackoverflow so I'm not so good at posting code and examples :-)

Comment: `    $("#myId").draggable({ snap: ".weekday-wrapper", grid: [ 10, 10 ],  drag: function(event, ui) { $('#myId').addClass('newClass')} });`

Comment: My problem is that I want to hide the divs that has NOT been moved, the divs that dont have the class "moved"

Comment: function showHideImages(){
    //document.querySelector("#wrapper").style.gridTemplateColumns = "300px 1fr";

    let moved = document.getElementsByClassName('newClass');
        if (moved.length > 0) {
           // document.getElementsByClassName('newClass')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
           $('.ui-draggable:not(.newClass)').hide();
           document.querySelector('#hideShowButton').innerHTML='Show images';
        }else{
            $('.ui-draggable:not(.newClass)').show();
           document.querySelector('#hideShowButton').innerHTML='Hide images';
        }
 };

Comment: You can use a alternate selector: `$(".draggable").not(".moved").hide()`, for example. this would select all items that have not been moved.